# One domain and multiple website in folders

Tags: seo, domains, subdomain, multiple-domains

I am going to create a network with one domain, e.g. `example.com` then going to manage my websites in **folders**. Look below for example:

```
www.example.com/market
www.example.com/freebies
www.example.com/personalblog
www.example.com/shop
```

Consider that all four websites have different design and codes. From SEO perspective, is it recommended or I should use **subdomains** or buy **four domains** for each website?

Answer (score 2):

It will definitely be better to use subdomains in this case.

Subdomains are represented as `abc.example.com`, `def.example.com`, `xyz.example.com` and can be accessed using the following URLs: `http://abc.example.com` or `http://example.com/abc`.

You don't need buying individual domain names to achieve the same.

Answer (score 0):

The reason to split them by sub-domain or into individual domains would be to make it easy to transfer or sell them later.

Which isn't to say that starting in a folder and then moving to a domain isn't possible, but it comes with some SEO risks.  I transfered one of my projects from a sub-domain of my website to full domain and lost a fair amount of Google traffic for about 8 months (although it eventually came back).

Comment: You mean that if I want to transfer my folders to standalone domain, it causes problems.

Comment: Correct.  Since I did so, Google did add the "change of address" feature to webmaster tools.  However it is "Restricted to root level domains only".  So it won't help for a situation where you move a sub-domain or folder into its own domain.

Comment: I appreciate your answer

Comment: if the market, freebies, personalblog, shop are all on topic with one another then you should not split it down into sub domains since your adding more content to the main site and more authority. Just my personal opinion and believe it'll be easier to rank it easier without the sub domains.

Comment: @bybe, If I got you right, I have to buy four domains, right??

Comment: @User1212 if the content of the 4 folders is not related, buying 4 separate domains with keywords in them would be your best bet, from an SEO point of view.

Comment: @nathangiesbrecht, Thanks. Yeah, they are not related.

Comment: @User1212 Then you'd be best off buying different domains for each "folder".

Answer (score 0):

When your pages are made of unique content (not sharing the same!) then use unique domains for each of them. This would allow you to optimize them for individual google ranking.  Otherwise I would recommend you subdomains - they are technical treated by google as folders but have better readability for human readers.